# Hive table creation with a default value

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a table in RDBMS like so:

```
create table test (sno number, entry_date date default sysdate).
```

Now I want to create a table in hive with a structure as adding a default value to a column.

Comment: What did you try ? What exactly is the problem you are facing ? Show some code.

Answer (score 3):

Hive currently doesn't support the feature of adding default value to any column while creating a table.
As a workaround load data into a temporary table and use the `insert overwrite table` statement to add the current date and time into the main table.

1. Create a temporary table:

   `create table test (sno number);`
2. Load data into the table:
3. Create final table:

   `create table final_table (sno number, createDate string);`
4. Finally load the data from temp `test` table to the final table:

   `insert overwrite table final_table select sno, FROM_UNIXTIME( UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), 'dd/MM/YYYY' ) from test;`

Comment: instead of creating stg table we can create like this.  create table final (sno int, jdate date); insert into final select 1 , substr(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),1,10); insert into final select MAX(sno)+1 , substr(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()),1,10) from final;

Answer (score 2):

Hive doesn't support DEFAULT fields

Doesn't mean you can't do it, though. Just a two step process of creating one "staging" table, then inserting into a second table and selecting that "default" value.

[Adding a default value to a column while creating table in hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033524/adding-a-default-value-to-a-column-while-creating-table-in-hive?rq=1)

Since you mention,

> I've table in RDBMS

You could also use your existing table, and use [**Sqoop**](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_basic_usage) to import the data into Hive.

Comment: I'm not importing any data through sqoop. Just I'm trying to create replica of RDBMS table in hive.