# Add column with default values in Hive

Tags: sql, hive, insert, sql-update, insert-update

I'm new in Hive, i use ***Hive 1.1.0-cdh5.11.1,*** my question is simple in SQL but in Hive it seems different.

I want to add 2 new columns *(column2,column3)* in one table *table1* for each column one constant/default value, like :

```
insert into table1(column2,column3) values (values2, DEFAULT, values3, DEFAULT)
```

but it doesn't work.
I tried to create another table table2 with 2 columns *(c1, c2)* and one row with 2 values: *value2, value3* and to do :

```
INSERT (OVERWRITE) INTO table1(column2,column3)
SELECT c1,c2 FROM table2
WHERE table1.column1 IS NOT NULL
```

I searched a lot of time with different solutions ... 
Anyone can help me ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: try this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033524/adding-a-default-value-to-a-column-while-creating-table-in-hive?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

In hive 3.0, we can create the table with ‘default’ constrain on column, in insert statement if we don’t specify the column value, default value will be inserted. Please refer to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-18726 and https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=75969407 for details. Thanks.